# Trouble creating pandas pivot table with preexisting Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to the Pandas module, and am trying to create a pivot table from my Excel file.

Here's my code:

```
excel = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
df = excel.parse
df1 = df[['Product Description', 'Supervisor']]

table1 = pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ['Supervisor'],
                           columns = ['Product Description'],
                           values = ['Product Description'],
                           aggfunc = [lambda x: len(x)], fill_value = 0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)
table1.to_excel(writer, 'Pivot Table')
writer.save()


workbook.save(filename)
```

It's giving me this error: `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Supervisor and Product Description are the two columns that i'm using to create the pivot table. Is this error happening because I can't reference the columns like that? Supervisor and Product description are the values in the first cell of each column. Do I have to reference the columns in some other way?

Comment: On which line is it giving you the error?

Comment: This line:  `df1 = df[['Product Description', 'Supervisor']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parse` is a method (function attached to an object). So you need parentheses after the method name i.e. `df = excel.parse()`.

See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) for details on how to supply arguments to the function call.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that mistake out. What would I pass the parse function in order to make this work? I tried giving it `sheetname = 0` but then it gave me this error: `KeyError: "['Supervisor'] not in index"`

Comment: Please post your DataFrame or a sample of it (click edit in the original question to add it).

Comment: Would I do that by just writing `print df1` ?

Comment: That will do it. Then copy and paste the results.

Comment: For some reason when I tried to print the DataFrame it was telling me that Supervisor was not in the index. Then I removed it from the declaration of df1 and then printed it and it printed out this http://paste.ubuntu.com/20320550/

Comment: Try printing `df` instead of `df1`.

Comment: Also, please open a new question. That way if someone is reading this, they will know the answer to the question originally posed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117951/discussion-between-alex-and-hleggs).